# How to ajust line height without messing up the text's "hitbox"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a title with slogun underneath in my header.

however, by default those 2 lines of text have WAY too much space between them, so i figured id use line height, which fixes the issue perfectly.. however doing so f*ks up the "hitbox" of the slogun.

i wanna use flexbox with justify-content to center both vertically inside of my header.. but with the messed up slogun "hitbox" this no longer works, as it centers the main title and the newly 2px tall hitbox of the 20px tall slogun

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(61, 61, 61);
    padding: 15px;
}

/* this is where i would place the line height. remove comment tags to see result */
/* header p{
    line-height: 5px;
} */
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>I'm a centered Title</h1>
    <p>Cool Slogun underneath!</p>
</header>
```

---

SCREENSHOTS FOR "HITBOX" EXPLENATION ig..

- Blue hitbox containing title and slogun.. neat
  [image: Blue hitbox containing title and slogun.. neat]
- Blue hitbox after line height.. yikes
  [image: Blue hitbox after line height.. yikes]

aka, how do i get my slogun and title closer together without messing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding the line-height to the Header itself and not the p?

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(61, 61, 61);
    padding: 15px;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <h1>I'm a centered Title</h1>
    <p>Cool Slogun underneath!</p>
</header>
```

Comment: wowww, i tried that initially but it messed up my whole header... guess i forgot to test it with a bigger number.. it still seems to mess up the hitbox but fixes the centering issue, thank you so much

Comment: i just applied this to the actual website im working on and uhhhhhhhhh...
it makes my title and slogun move up.. but not any closer together

Comment: figured it out... cleaned up my code in the process.. thanks again lol